# A C function that inserts number into a linked list in ascending order

Tags: c, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list, function-definition

This is my function:

```
void IntListInsertInOrder (IntList L, int v)
{
    struct IntListNode *n = newIntListNode (v);
    if (L->first == NULL) { //case a, empty list
        L->first = L->last = n;
        L->size ++;
        return;
    }
    else if (v <= L->first->data) { // case b, smallest value
        n->next = L->first;
        L->first = n;
    }
    else if (v >= L->last->data) { // case c, largest value
        L->last->next = n;
        L->last = n;
    }
    else if (v > L->first->data && v <= L->first->next->data) { // case d, second-smallest value
        n->next = L->first->next;
        L->first->next = n;
    }
    else { //case f, value in the middle
        struct IntListNode *curr = L->first;
        while (curr->next->data < v) {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        n->next = curr->next;
        curr->next = n;
    }
    L->size ++;
    return;
}
```

when i put random lists of 10 numbers into it, 3/10 sorted correctly. the errors seem to be in the last part but it looks exactly like solutions i found online.

Comment: See the [add_ordered() function](https://pastebin.com/R2AewR3A) at this link. (your `first` and `last` appear to be `head` and `tail` in the linked function)

Comment: What is the sequence of insertions making up an incorrect list? Show one example

Comment: @Yuyan_Li Show how the list is defined.

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out. I forgot to add`&& curr-> != NULL`in the condition of the last while loop. After I added that all the test cases passed.

Comment: How could that be a problem? Reaching that "while" loop at the end would imply that the inserted element is strictly larger than second element and strictly smaller than last element which means that "curr->next" would never be null. In the worst case, curr->next will eventually reach "L->last" which is strictly larger. So something is wrong in your reasoning here

Comment: I keep thinking about this, somehow it magically fixed the issue although I have no idea as to why.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is too complicated, has many if conditions and as a result it is error-prone and unreadable.

You did not show the list definition but I can guess that you have a two-sided singly-linked list because nowhere in the code there is a reference to a data member named `prev`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be simply defined.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

typedef struct List
{
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
    size_t size;
} List;

int insert_in_order( List *list, int data )
{
    Node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;

        Node **current = &list->head;

        while ( *current != NULL && !( data < ( *current )->data ) )
        {
            current = &( *current )->next;
        }

        new_node->next = *current;

        if ( *current == NULL )
        {
            list->tail = new_node;
        }

        *current = new_node;

        ++list->size;
    }

    return success;
}

void clear( List *list )
{
    while ( list->head != NULL )
    {
        Node *current = list->head;
        list->head = list->head->next;
        free( current );
    }
}

void display( const List *list )
{
    printf( "There are %zu nodes in the list\n", list->size );
    printf( "They are: " );

    for ( const Node *current = list->head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d -> ", current->data );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    List list = { .head = NULL, .tail = NULL, .size = 0 };

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    const size_t N = 10;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        insert_in_order( &list, rand() % ( int )N );
    }

    display( &list );

    clear( &list );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
There are 10 nodes in the list
They are: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> 6 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

Comment: This is a university lab challenge so I can't change anything other than this function. Thank you for this amazing solution, I feel like I learned a lot just reading your code.